# JSTL compare to tab character

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is it possible to use JSTL to compare with a tab character?

For example, I need to check whether a String stored in the user's session contains a tab character in it.

The following returns an exception:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(Delimiter, 'Tab') or Delimiter eq '\\u0009'}">selected</c:if>
```

> Message: /jsp/mapSetup.jsp(88,15) "${fn:contains(Delimiter, 'Tab') or
>   Delimiter eq '\u0009'}" contains invalid expression(s):
>   javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${fn:contains(Delimiter, 'Tab')
>   or Delimiter eq '\u0009'}

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using `'&#9;'`, like this:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(Delimiter, '&#9;')}">selected</c:if>
```